# Universal Quantification and existential quantification question

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, quantifiers

Im working on this problem but not sure if Im using negation correctly

Please express the following statement using the universal quantification (“for all” quantifier) and the existential quantification ("there exists” quantifier):

Not all numbers are greater than $2$ $$\lnot \forall x\;(N(x)\land G(x)) $$

There exist some numbers which are less than $0$ $$ \exists x\;(N(x)\to L(x))$$

Comment: The first one should read $\lnot \forall(N(x)\to G(x))$, and the second, $\exists x(N(x) \land L(x))$, assuming in the first case, that $G(x)$ is the predicate "x is greater than 2", and L(x) is the predicate "x is less than 0"

Comment: Why not using suitable arithmetical predicates and constants ? $\lnot \forall x \in \mathbb N (x > 2)$ and $\exists x \in \mathbb N (x < 0)$.

Comment: In a set theory that disallows the existence of a universal set, for any set $Q$ and proposition $P$ we have: $\exists x:[x\in Q \to P]$ regardless of whether $P$ is true or false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universal quantification is restricted by conditional.

'All things $Q$ are $P$', 'All things have property $P$ if they have property $Q$' ... $\forall x~(Q(x)\to P(x))$

Notice how $\forall x~(Q(x)\land P(x))$ claims all things have both properties, which is *not* what we wish to say.

---

Existential quantification is restricted by conjunction.

'Some things $Q$ are $P$', 'Some things with property $Q$ also have property $P$' ... $\exists x~(Q(x)\land P(x))$

Notice how $\exists x~(Q(x)\to P(x))$ may be satisfied if there is nothing with both properties as long as there is something without property $Q$ or with property $P$.   (A conditional is true if the *antecedant is false* or the *consequent true*.)   So that is clearly *not* what we wish to say.

Answer (score 0):

The first one should be  $$¬∀x(N(x)\implies G(x))$$

The second one should  be $$\exists x(N(x) \wedge L(x))$$